# What is the proper word to say "terrorist hood" in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct word for the thing that gangsters have on their head during hold ups?

[image: balaclava]

Comment: Maybe you ought to describe the thing you have in mind. Otherwise you're going to have people running through all possible types of headgear.

Answer (score 20):

[*Balaclava*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaclava_%28clothing%29).

Comment: Who's downvoting these answers and why? *Ski mask* and *balaclava* are synonyms for the headwear that I think the OP is asking for.

Comment: nah, balaclavas don't have a mouth opening. OP's now posted a pic with a mouth opening, so balaclava is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to run yourself down. [Here](http://www.fotosearch.com/photos-images/balaclava.html) are pictures labelled "balaclava", many of which have mouth openings. Also, I don't recall *ever* hearing a newsreader in the UK refer to rioters/looters wearing "ski masks", but they use "balaclava" quite often (although just "hooded" or "masked" are probably more common anyway). So I'm upvoting yours as the more standard expression, even if your distinction is theoretically correct.

Answer (score 15):

I believe you're thinking of a *ski mask*, a (usually black) tight cloth mask that covers the whole head except for eyes and possibly mouth. *Balaclava* is also used, but *ski mask* is by far the more common term in American English.

Comment: Who's downvoting these answers and why? *Ski mask* and *balaclava* are synonyms for the headwear that I think the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Agreed. Now that the OP has added a picture, this is obviously the right answer. +1.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I downvoted the other answer because I didn't think it was right, and because it's just one word with some padding characters.

Comment: it's a single word request. why would the answer require more than one word?

Comment: @myqlarson: Forgive me for giving a different psychic answer than yours. In any case, *ski mask* is unequivocally the American term. I'll edit to add.

Comment: note ski masks are often made of hard protective plastic with built-in goggles, worn over the face in connection with a helmet, so Balaclava is far less likely to misguide the reader.

Comment: In America the term "balaclava" would be unknown.